# How to do 301 Redirect from non-slashed root to slashed root domain on ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

ASP.NET MVC 4 website that has the domain http://mosaically.com and http://mosaically.com/ and both of them are returning 200 OK response. I want mosaically.com to do 301 redirect to mosaically.com/ with the slash for SEO reasons. Is there any way to do this in MVC 4? I'd prefer to do this in MVC rather than trying something with IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out it can't be done, even if you're Chuck Norris says Google

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html

"Rest assured that for your root URL specifically, example.com is equivalent to example.com/ and can’t be redirected even if you’re Chuck Norris."

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`Url Rewrite module`](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) in IIS to achieve this task. Here's a [`nice step by step article`](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/03/31/seo-made-easy-with-iis-url-rewrite-2-0-seo-templates.aspx) illustrating how you could enable it. Here's how a sample rewrite rule might look like in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer> 
    <rewrite> 
        <rules> 
            <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1"> 
                <match url="(.*)" /> 
                <conditions> 
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mosaically\.com$" negate="true" /> 
                </conditions> 
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mosaically.com/{R:1}" /> 
            </rule> 
        </rules> 
    </rewrite> 
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: That causes a redirect loop.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in MVC??? This is much better handled at the IIS level - it's global and faster.

Comment: I guess I want to do it in IIS, but it's not working right now because of redirect loop.

Comment: Actually, it's not working at all. Doesn't do anything if I just copy paste that into my web.config

Comment: Which web server are you using to test this? Are you running in integrated pipeline mode if you are using IIS 7+?

Comment: IIS 7.5 so above code as is above doesn't do anything for me, and if i  do negate false, then it causes redirect loop.

Comment: It seems I get both 200 or both 301 even if I put two conditions into the rewrite rule and try to not match the one with /

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use like that

in you global.aspx

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            string rudsiteurl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            if (rudsiteurl.Contains("http://www.mosaically.com"))
            {
                Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://www.mosaically.com/");
            }

        }
```

i think this will help you...